# Move a program from one computer to another with no installer

Tags: windows-7, reinstall

Hi,

I have a program back on my old computer that works just fine there but then I got a new computer and I want to have it there as well. However, I dont have the installer and I cant get it back because the developer site is offline and not coming back.

How can I identify all the necessary files and components (like registry values, etc.) so I can copy them from my old computer exactly the way they are onto my new computer to make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: If the program will work without installing it then just cope the installation folder. If it works great, if it doesn't, then you have to install the program

Comment: The program works fine on my OLD computer but it wont work on my new one if its not installed first and I dont have the installer hence my question.

Comment: You can use either a debugger or a system logger. see [See what files/registry keys are being accessed by application in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509383/see-what-files-registry-keys-are-being-accessed-by-application-in-windows)

Comment: Do you know if it is MSI based?  

Can you find reference to the app under say: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\  Does it have a LocalPackage value?

Can you find it under:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
or say:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
What might the UninstallString values be?

Comment: I found some strings in registry but I think they are too many to keep track.

Comment: "It doesn't work without being installed" doesnt tell us very much

Comment: Did you find a value for LocalPackage?

Comment: Can you provide the name of that program?

Comment: No, I could find that value. The program is called FHL switcher. It was developed by a fan of the FIFA soccer games and he is not updating it anymore. When you run it for the first time on a computer, it tries to download some files, I guess from his website which is offline now so I think thats the reason.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the exe you have?  I assume that if it does download files, there is a chance that with something like Wireshark running, you might be able to see the HTTP requests for files.  If you then know the first file name, maybe you have that on your original computer along with subsequent files.  You could potentially mock up the repository to understand the files being requested.  I assume it does no validation at least at the download phase so there is potential to put any file with the same name/path on a local site to "learn" the file set being requested.

Comment: There is no link, but I can send it to you by mail if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a commercial program like [PCmover](http://web.laplink.com/product/pcmover-home/) or [Total Uninstall](https://www.martau.com/document/transfer-programs-to-new-pc.php). I use the latter to monitor the installation of new software on systems, so I know what files and registry entries have been added or modified during a software installation, but it can also be used for moving programs from one system to another. Alternatively, if you know the URL for the developer's website, you may still be able to download the software via the Internet Archives's [WayBack Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_machine). If you are unfamiliar with the WayBack Machine it is a project to archive the web by periodically copying sites' content to an archive to preserve content for posterity.